# How to set color effect on document(image) using OpenCV(java)

Tags: java, android, opencv, imagefilter

currently, I'm working on a document scanner project who captures and filter document with different effects and color but I'm a beginner to work with OpenCV.

but, now I understand how **medianBlurFilter** , **gaussianBlurFilter** , **cannyFilter** and **bilateralFilter** works.

just I am starting to do this type of filter with the use of OpenCV but I can't understand how to achieve this.

**Input :**

[image]

**How to achieve this?:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you can either play with the contrast or adjust each individual BGR channel

Comment: can you guide me on how to achieve these color effects on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//bitmap is a normal document image

        Bitmap newB = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newB);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(sp,255, 0, 0));

        Mat src = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, src);

        Mat dst = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(newB, dst);

        Core.addWeighted(src, 1f, dst, 0.5f, 0.5, dst);


//bitmapNew is a filtered document image

        Bitmap bitmapNew = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Utils.matToBitmap(dst, bitmapNew);
```